# AC21 to port my approved I-140 to a job of similar description

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard, employment, interview

My employment-based I-485 (EB1-b) is now passing 180 days. I did not yet find a job within my H1B grace period. So I'm planning to use my EAD for possible jobs, and use AC21 for porting my approved I-140 (PD in Sep 2017).

My AoS is in a month or so, and I will need to be employed at a "similar job" at the time of my interview (look at my [previous question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13404/do-i-need-to-be-employed-at-the-moment-of-aos-interview-for-my-employment-based)). But just some googling, I see that USCIS SOC codes has changed since 2018. My I-140 was under 15-1132 (software developer- applications) is no more there.

How is "similar job description" determined? Is it OK as long as it is within "15" major category? And btw, is it OK if the next job is a postdoc (which is usually 1-year contract)?

I will use my EAD so I'm so concerned.